# Как реализовать переход между страницей A и страницей B и обратно?

Tags: java, android

только осваиваю Android-разработку и столкнулся с проблемой которую не могу решить самостоятельно. Я смог сделать переход с главной страницы на вторую страницу при помощи кнопки, но обратно, на главную страницу не получается, в приложений выдаёт ошибку. При этом, если я перенаправлю переход на какую-то 3 страницу, которой я прописал значение DEFAULT в AndroidManifest.xml, всё работает. Проблема заключается в том что я не могу вернуться на страницу с категорий LAUNCHER из страницы с категорий DEFAULT.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.hp.testapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainMenu">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Training">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Training" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainMenu.java:** Здесь всё работает, кнопка перекидывает на следующую страницу

```java
package com.example.hp.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button trng_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton () {
        trng_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trng_btn);

        trng_btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (View v) {
                        Intent nextPage2 = new Intent(".Training");
                        startActivity(nextPage2);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

**Training.java:** Скорее всего здесь и проблема, т.к. когда я нажимаю кнопку "Вернуться назад" приложение просто вылетает, хотя сделал всё также как и в MainMenu.java

```
package com.example.hp.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Training extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button back_btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_training);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton () {
        back_btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn1);

        back_btn1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (View v) {
                        Intent backPage = new Intent(".MainMenu");
                        startActivity(backPage);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы хотите вернуться, то можно просто закрыть текущую активити, вместо открытия новой. Просто вызовете `finish()`. Также не стоит хардкодить имена классов. Попробуйте так интент сформировать: `Intent backPage = new Intent(Training.this, MainMenu.getClass());`

Comment: Ну и если у вас ошибка - надо приводить в вопросе её лог + указать строку возникновения ошибки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ошибка происходит в самом приложений, при нажатий на кнопку приложение вылетает. А так, сама программа компилируется. Сейчас попробую ваши способы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не забывайте о UX (опыт пользователя), поведение приложения должно быть подсознательно понятно пользователю. Возьмите несколько приложений и посмотрите как видут себя приложения в тех или инных ситуациях, сравните с тем что вы хотите сделать и повторите поведение. `finish()` отличное решение, но в вашей ситуации лучше воспользоваться кнопкой назад, а на экране что-то на подобие [стандартного](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J25a0.png) и в обработчике вызвать тоже самое поведение кнопки назад.

```
btBack.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(View view) {
    onBackPressed();
})
```

Код выше вызовёт метод `onBackPressed()`, его можно перегрузить:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Изменение данного метода, можно изменить поведение кнопки назад и например сохранить данные, но не забывайте об опыте пользователя.

Вернёмся к методу `finish()`, если у вас есть поведение с разделением кнопок на "Cancel" 
и "Save", то лучше конечно в кнопке save сохранять данные и закрывать активити методом `finish()`, а по кнопке назад "Cancel" пользователь будет понимать о закрытии данного экрана без соханения данных.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь всё работает как я задумывал